# MongoDB: querying on a field in an array of embedded documents is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My document in MongoDB is like this:

```
{ 
   "data":{ 
      "groupName":"sample",
      "users": [ 
         { 
            "_id":new ObjectId(),
            "mobNum":"29857903289",
            "isAdmin":"true"
         },
         { 
            "_id":new ObjectId(),
            "mobNum":"87532480923",
            "isAdmin":"false"
         },
      ]
   }
}
```

`users` is an array of embedded-ducuments in `groupusers` collection. When I try to query the embedded sub field like this
`db.groupusers.find( { "users.$.mobNum": "29857903289" } )`,  it returns me no response.

Problem is in querying the embedded sub field. I'm new to use MongoDB. Don't know how to query the embedded array of sub field. Not sure what to do.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `mobnum` vs. `mobNum`?

Comment: i tried both, they are giving no response

Comment: Well, go and [edit] your question to use the same spelling for one. You can't possibly expect this to work if you spell it differently, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here use this

```
db.getCollection('YOUR_COLLECTION_HERE').find({
  "data.users": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "mobNum": "29857903289"
    }
  }
}})
```

Comment: I think something is broken with latest mongo version 4.2. I tried downloading 4.0.4 docker container of mongo and the same query returns correct values. Anyhow, thanks for your help